# How can I fix ValueError: Too many values to unpack" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to populate a dictionary with the contents of my text file ("out3.txt").

My text file is of the form:

```
vs,14100

mln,11491

the,7973

cts,7757
```

...and so on...

I want my dictionary `answer` to be of the form:

```
answer[vs]=14100

answer[mln]=11491
```

...and so on...

My code is:

```
import os
import collections
import re
from collections import defaultdict

answer = {}
answer=collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('out3.txt', 'r+') as istream:
    for line in istream.readlines():
        k,v = line.strip().split(',')
        answer[k.strip()].append( v.strip())
```

But, I get:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suspect one of the lines in the input file has more than one comma. Try `grep ',.*,' out3.txt`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have empty `line`s in your input file and I suspect one of the `line`s that you have not shared with us has too many commas in it (hence "too many values to unpack").

You can protect against this, like so:

```
import collections

answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('out3.txt', 'r+') as istream:
    for line in istream:
        line = line.strip()
        try:
            k, v = line.split(',', 1)
            answer[k.strip()].append(v.strip())
        except ValueError:
            print('Ignoring: malformed line: "{}"'.format(line))

print(answer)
```

**Note:** By passing `1` into [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), everything after the first comma will be assigned to `v`; if this is not desired behaviour and you'd prefer these lines to be rejected, you can remove this argument.

Comment: The first `answer = {}` can be removed. The open file should always be closed.

Comment: Thanks @pepr, I missed this when I removed the rest of the cruft.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution doesn't give your desired output. You'll have (assuming it worked), `answer['vs'] = [14100]`, the below does what you intended:

```
import csv

with open('out3.txt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  answer = {line[0].strip():line[1].strip() for line in reader if line}
```

Comment: +1 for using `csv` (unless the input file is very specific, simple).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `collections` here. Plain old dict is enough:

```
answer = {}
with open('out3.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        lst = line.split(',')
        if len(lst) == 2:
            k = lst[0].strip()
            v = lst[1].strip()
            answer[k] = v

print(answer['mln'])
print(answer.get('xxx', 'not available'))
```

Notice the `answer.get()` is similar to `answer[]` but you can supply the defaul value.

You should not use `.readlines()` in the loop. Even the empty line contains the newline character. This way the test `if line:` does not detects the empty lines. Or you have to strip (or `rstrip`) it first, or you can split the line to the list and test the number of elements.