# error in exporting a file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file with two columns and more that 6000 rows and would like to export it to a dictionary in python.
here is a part of big file:

```
ENST00000589805,CCCTCCCGGACTCCTCTCCCCGGCCGGCCGGCAAGAGTTTACAA
ENST00000376512,GTTGCCGAGGGGACGGGCCGGGCAGATGCCAAC
ENST00000314332,TTTAAG
```

I wrote this function:

```
def file_to_dict(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    answer = {}
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split(',')
        answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    return answer
```

I tried that for a small file and worked perfectly. but when I tried that for my big file, it gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in file_to_dict
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I tried to find the solution but did not manage. do you guys know how to resolve it?
BTW, the dictionary would be like this:

```
{'ENST00000589805':'CCCTCCCGGACTCCTCTCCCCGGCCGGCCGGCAAGAGTTTACAA', 'ENST00000376512': 'GTTGCCGAGGGGACGGGCCGGGCAGATGCCAAC', 'ENST00000314332': 'TTTAAG'}
```

Comment: you're assuming there's only one comma in each line of your text file - is this necessarily true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix ValueError: Too many values to unpack" in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403371/how-can-i-fix-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-in-python)

Comment: Hint: `k, v = "a,b,c".split(",")` raises the same error as mentioned by you in question.

Comment: in the case of more then one comma appearing on a line do `help(str.split)` and read the part about the `maxsplit` argument

Answer (score 0):

The most likely (but not the only possible) cause is that you have a newline at the end if your input file. This would break the `split()` call in the manner you describe. One way to fix this is as follows:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
      k, v = line.split(',')
      answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()
```

It is equally possible that your input file breaks your assumptions in some other way. To handle this, you should beef up the error checking in your code.

Comment: `k,v = []` would raise an error stating `not enough values to unpack` where as `k,v = [1,2,3]` will raise one stating `too many values to unpack` so empty lines would not cause the error the OP is getting.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the lines probably has more than one comma in it. Because you're splitting by commas, it's being broken up into >2 variables, but you've only specified two names. Find the line with the extra comma and try to fix that, or give an extra variable name if needed.